# Error Handling with HTTPWebRequests, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've looked around and couldn't find an answer so I thought i'd ask it here.
I have a program the calls an API with login info passed in the header and the server returns some info upon authentication. The problem is if the user creds are incorrect, the program crashes and throws an exception. The error is 401. How do it catch this, and tell the user?
My code is:

```
Dim request = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://myurl.com"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)

    request.Method = "GET"

    request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken)

    request.ContentLength = 0
    Dim responseContent As String
    Using response = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()
            MessageBox.Show(responseContent)
        End Using
    End Using
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a try catch statement

```
try
   'My error prone code
catch ex as Exception
   'Handle my error
end try
```

---

```
    Try

        Dim request = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://myurl.com"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)

        request.Method = "GET"

        request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken)

        request.ContentLength = 0
        Dim responseContent As String
        Using response = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()
                MessageBox.Show(responseContent)
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```